# Css menu becomes transparent over javascript

Tags: java, css, menu, transparent

I'm trying to implement a css menu in a website, and have run into a problem.

Note: The css is in the file, it's the only thing under  The javascript is called http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js and it's defined on the header as well.
The menu is called cssmenu.

The problem is, on that css menu, when hovering over **contact**, the background colors are transparent, and with my limited knowledge on the subject, I really don't know how to fix this.
The css menu is not my creation, I found it on the web. I have modified many properties that I knew how, but got stuck there.

Comment: So you want the bg colors to not be transparent?

Comment: Btw your writing your webpage pretty odd, it looks like the retro way of doing it. Try using divs and ul's instead of tables, and only use tables for emails and table data

Comment: @SimonPertersen I know, i used frontpage 03 for most of that. haha
Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bump up the z-index of the main menu `<ul>` so it always appears over the ShareThis bar:

```
ul.cssmenu {
    display: block;
    zoom: 1;
    float: left;
    position:relative; /* allows the z-index to be effective -- http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index */
    z-index:100; /* makes the menu appear above the ShareThis widget */
}
```

Comment: Incredible!
Thank you so much @froddd, not only for answering the question, but providing the link with the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, the issue is that the menu is positions incorrectly on the z axis.

Try adding something like this to bring it forward on top of the buttons:

```
.cssmenum {
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

z-index seems to be the right solution, I have just checked now.

However I have also noticed that tabels have been used to build the menu with social icons. I suggest creating a DIV and use CSS to position it where needed.

Answer (score 0):

add z-index:2;

```
ul.cssmenu, ul.cssmenu ul
```

in this class and you will get your result :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a ground zero for your z-index like this

```
body{position:relative;
z-index:0;}
```

Then you can give each of your menu's a z-index

```
.div1{z-index:1;}
.div2{z-index:5;}
```